# How can I make IE11 run in IE8 mode?

Tags: development-environment

The Development tools in IE11 no longer seem to let you run as IE 8.
Please do not tell me I don't need to do this as this is for SharePoint and I have no control over how it acts.
I am trying to add in a user and you have to run as IE8 or it errors out.

I hit F12 to bring up the development tools.
I change Document Mode to 8.
And I change User Agent String to Internet Explorer 8.

Then I go to my SharePoint site and try to add myself in with the people picker.
And I get a yellow screen with an xml schema error in the people picker popup dialog.

All this worked in IE 10 running as IE8 before windows update updated me to IE 11.

Comment: were you able to get a resolution to this? I am also facing the same problem. My page worked in IE8, but with IE11 even after changing the mode, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Developer Tools to change IE Compatibility mode version

Navigate to the site for which you want to change IE Compatibility mode version

1. Display Internet Explorer Developer Tools:
       Press F12.
       OR
       Press Alt, then follow the menu path Tools > Developer Tools.
2. In Developer Tools panel
       Change Browser mode to the desired version
       Change Document mode to the desired version

[Reference](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+change+your+setting+for+Compatibility+mode+for+Internet+Explorer)